# upload a jpeg & download a pdf - swift + rest

Tags: ios, swift, rest, http, ios8

I'v a pretty simple use case wherein, I need to upload a jpeg & download a pdf from a rest api. I am facing below mentioned problems & I'v done due diligence (to the best of my knowledge) to try to get a solution from SO & google, but I haven't been successful, yet.

questions :

1. sendPdf method does indeed send multiple fragments of data (confirmed by running a pkt sniffer) but My code in playground recieves response as nil.
   Use cases, but to no vain :

   1 Tried content-type = application/pdf
   2 Tried content-type = application/octet-stream
2. SaveFile method indeed creates the file viz. img_1 & img_2, but picture viewer is not able to open the photograph, meaning, some mismatch in bits while re-compiling the bytestream as pdf.
   Use cases, but to no vain :

   1 Tried DataInputStream
   2 Tried ImageIO functions alongwith ByteArrayInputStream

rest api :

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        createOutput(request, response);
    }

    private void createOutput(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  {
        PrintWriter out_response = null;
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        saveFile(request);
        sendPdf(response);
    }

    private void sendPdf(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

        //response.setContentType("application/pdf"); 
        response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\dwalia\\Desktop\\abc.pdf");  
      if(fin !=null){
        BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(fin);  
        BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());  
        int ch =0;  
        while((ch=bin.read())!=-1)  
        {  
            bout.write(ch);  
        }  
        bin.close();  
        fin.close();  
        bout.close();
      }
    }

    private void saveFile(HttpServletRequest request) {

        byte[] data = new byte[0];
        byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
        int bytesRead;

        try {
            DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(request.getInputStream());
            while ((bytesRead = din.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                byte[] newData = new byte[data.length + bytesRead];
                System.arraycopy(data, 0, newData, 0, data.length);
                System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, newData, data.length, bytesRead);
                data = newData;
            }
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\dwalia\\Desktop\\img_1.png");
            fos.write(data);
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  

        try {
            BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
            File outputfile = new File("C:\\Users\\dwalia\\Desktop\\img_2.png");
            if(img != null) ImageIO.write(img, "png", outputfile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

My xcode playground code (SRWeb library : https://github.com/sraj/Swift-SRWebClient):

1. Trying to upload a png & download a pdf in a single go :

var image_src = UIImage(named : "India")
var params = ["username":"uname", "password":"pwd"]
var img_data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image_src, 100)

SRWebClient.POST("http://169.254.54.114:8080/sample/hello_world_servlet")
                 .data(img_data, fieldName: "signature", data: params)
                 .send(
                       {(response:AnyObject!, status:Int) -> Void in
                            println(status) <-- 200                       
                            if let response_json: AnyObject = response {
                                println(response as! String) <-- nothing, response == nil
                            }
                       }
                      )

2. Trying to download pdf only :

SRWebClient.GET("http://169.254.54.114:8080/sample/hello_world_servlet",
    success:{
        (response:AnyObject!, status:Int) -> Void in
        println("\(status) \(response)") <-- "Data nil"

        if let response_data: AnyObject = response {
            println(response_data) <-- nothing, response == nil
        }
    }, failure:{
        (error:NSError!) -> Void in
        println(error.localizedDescription) <-- nothing
    }
)
```